# Which Pipeline triggers the Logout when CookieAuthentication expires?

Tags: federated-authentication, authentication

Is there a pipeline that I can hook into, when the CookieAuthentication time, that has been defined in config, expires?

```
 <owin.initialize>
          <processor name="CookieAuthentication" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.Initialize.CookieAuthentication, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
                   resolve="true" patch:instead="processor[@name='CookieAuthentication']">
            <!-- Controls how much time the cookie will remain valid from the point it is created.
             Format: d:hh:mm:ss

             No matter the cookie is persistent or not, OWIN authentication will not pass the expired cookie.
             ExpireTimeSpan could be overwritten by the http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/cookieExp claim where
             the claim value is Unix time expressed as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. -->
            <ExpireTimeSpan>01:30:00</ExpireTimeSpan>
            <SlidingExpiration>true</SlidingExpiration>
          </processor>
        </owin.initialize>
```

As my user doesn't get logged out automatically from Keycloak, I need to call the logout endpoint myself when the session expires. The Owin Middleware is not been called, so I can't do it from there.

Comment: I don't think there is. This is not an action happening server side, unless the user happens to visit again with his or her expired cookie.

Comment: when the session expires, keycloak would ask user to re-auth , wont it ?

Comment: Unfortunatelly Keycloak doesn't. The session of the user never expires and it seems there ist still a cookie or something aktiv, which redirects the user back to sitecore without asking for username and password again. But the access and refresh cookie is no longer valid